# How to solve the ongoing problem with Visual Studio Code and warnings, MDN Reference and more?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, svelte

How do I disable typescript warnings and TS all together in Visual Studio Code for regular javascript files when working with sveltekit? When I create a project I say no to use of TS.

Actually, how do I disable the annoying popup with MDN Reference, warnings and what not in VSCode all together? This has been asked before, many times but I don't think there's a definite answer. Or has it? What is the problem? Why hasn't this been solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest version of the SvelteKit template (the one you get when initializing a new project) has fixed many of the issue that come up for those of us using regular JavaScript. (there is now also an option to have `type-checked JavaScript` which gives you hints about types without the stranglehold of TypeScript). So it could be worth starting a new project and copying over your components/pages.

To disable the general "hover" behaviour of VSCode, you can set this with

```
"editor.hover.enabled": "false"
```

But this cuts a lot of functionality of VSCode, at that moment you have merely a better looking version of notepad.

SvelteKit works perfectly fine with just regular JavaScript, it was actually developed without TypeScript originally because the developers felt that progress was faster without it, but that is of course very subjective.

Answer (score 4):

Change the `checkJs` property in jsconfig.json to `false`, if you're not into type checking that much..

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#checkJs

Answer (score -1):

Well, if you use `sveltekit` as a **Typescript** project so I'm not sure why you would want to use standard JS.

If you still consider to use JS, you have to disable the validation for javascript with

```
"javascript.validate.enable": false
```

in your editor's `settings.json`. But be aware that this disables **all built-in** syntax checking.

If you are specifically concerned about *import/export* errors, you could also add a `jsconfig.json` to your project, which includes:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "es2015"
    }
}
```

Regarding the MDN Popup. Not sure what exactly you are referencing to but have you tried to add

```
"editor.hover.enabled": false
```

to your `settings.json`? You could also hit `Ctrl` + `,` search for `MDN` and see what you can deselect.

Comment: Thanks but rather strange answer that doesn't solve the problem. You can use both JS and TS with sveltekit. Don't want to learn TS. Not now anyway. The annoying popups is a constant VS Code issue that I think should be dealt with in another way.

Comment: Typescript is just a superset of JavaScript, so of course you can use both. It just makes no sense using JS in a Typescript project since you loose all type checks and hints. So the line in `settings.json` did not work?

Comment: Thank you for you effort to help but I don't think you respect my question. It's not helping me. I don't want checks and hints with TS. It makes no sense using TS for me. I don't get them when working in JS for other projects. The hover thing is new ( I think). Can help. Thanks for that.

Comment: Well, I do respect your question and presented a possible solution for you to get rid of type checks and hints for your JS files - did the `javascript.validate.enable: false` work for you? Unfortunately, you can’t expect to get rid of Typescript when using a TS project. I’m not sure if there is a `sveltekit` written in standard JS, but I highly doubt it. So if you find the TS part of the project annoying, you might consider forking the project and rewrite in in JS.

Comment: Disabling hover worked. Was a while since a looked at this but many have complained about this behavior. Very annoy for CSS. Finally they did something about it. Of course it works with JavaScript. That's what they claim. Docs and tutorial is written for that.